# Array with key value string into Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am looking for some help, I am working on a piece of code for a client, the client currently have their analytics tag hardcoded to the page with all the key values being sent.

We are in the process of converting them to a new analytics platform using a tag management system, they have been able to update the majority of their platforms to create an object that the new analytics platform can reference but as this site is managed by a 3rd party they are unable to get this resolved in time for our release.

I have managed to successfully pull the tag and split the tag in to parameters:

```
var x = $('img[alt="MI_TAG"]').attr("src");
x.split("&");
```

Which creates the array:

```
1:"109=jsp.searchFlights.initial"
2:"117=Flight Only Journey"
3:"206=02/11/2017"
4:"208=03/11/2017"
5:"212=ALL"
```

What I want to do is take these array strings to create an object call "mi", like so:

```
109:"jsp.searchFlights.initial"
117:"Flight Only Journey"
204:""
205:""
206:"02/11/2017"
208:"03/11/2017"
```

Can someone help?
Thanks all for your help, I have managed to take some of the advice here and create the object and see it logging out:

```
var x = $('img[alt="MI_TAG"]').attr("src");
var split = x.split("&");
var arrayLength = split.length;
var arr = [];
var i = 0;
do {
  arr.push(split[i].replace('=',':'));
  arr.toString();
  console.log(arr);
  i += 1;
} while (i < arrayLength);

let mi = {};

arr.forEach(item=>{
    let tempArr = item.split(':');
    mi[tempArr[0]] = tempArr[1];
})

console.log(mi);
```

The issue I now seem to be facing is scope, I want my object to be globally referenceable, how do I do that?

Comment: Where're 204/5 coming from? It seems random just adding them to the output like that.

Comment: Hi Andy
I was copying a the object from a different page to use a illustration, sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using at least ECMAScript 5.1 you could use `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate over your array and produce the object.

```js
let myArray = ["109=jsp.searchFlights.initial", "117=Flight Only Journey", "206=02/11/2017", "208=03/11/2017", 
"212=ALL"];

let myObject = {};

myArray.forEach(item=>{
    let tempArr = item.split('=');
    myObject[tempArr[0]] = tempArr[1];
})

console.log(myObject);
```

Produces:

`{
  "109": "jsp.searchFlights.initial",
  "117": "Flight Only Journey",
  "206": "02/11/2017",
  "208": "03/11/2017",
  "212": "ALL"
}`

Answer (score 3):

From your array, use `reduce` - split on the `=` sign in your string, and create the object:

```
let newObject = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    let parts = item.split("=");
    obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: That's just a `for` loop. Why bother with `obj` and `reduce`?

Comment: OP I recommend you set a limit on that split, otherwise if another = appears the array will have more than 2 values in it.

Comment: By which I mean: `let newObject = {}; for (let item of arr) { let parts = item.split("="); newObject[parts[0]] = parts[1]; }`.

Comment: @melpomene - Yep - no real reason. I just like using `reduce` when I can.

Comment: @tymeJV Why not use `filter` instead? `let obj = {}; arr.filter(item => { let parts = item.split("="); obj[parts[0]] = parts[1]; return obj; })`?

Comment: @melpomene - Usually `filter` returns a subset of the original array - using `filter` to create an entirely new object seems wrong - if anything I'd use a `forEach`

Comment: @tymeJV And usually `reduce` is used to fold over a list of values and build up a result. Using `reduce` just to iterate seems wrong.

Comment: @melpomene - But it's not just iterating, it's creating a new object. I see your point tho - a regular loop would be better here, both for readability and general use case. Like I said before, I just like `reduce` :)

Comment: @tymeJV No, it's not. The object is created by `{}`, as in my version. Your code just loops over some values and sets attributes of the object, as does my code.

Comment: Then what's your point? Both your codes do the same thing. `reduce` is perfectly acceptable here.